# Timestamp in database 2 hours earlier

Tags: magento-1.9, database, timezone

When an order is placed, the date in the Magento backend is correct. When I check the database however, the timestamp is 2 hours earlier. The server time is correct, timezone in PHP and Magento backend is set to Europe/Brussels, which is correct. If I add a record in the database (Sequel Pro) with NOW(), date is also correct.

What am I missing here?
Must be Magento, right?

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps in the database are always in UTC to be timezone independent. Magento converts the timezone based on current users locale.

`Europe/Brussels` (DST) is UTC+2

Comment: So technically there's no problem? ;)

Comment: Yes, everything is fine.

Answer (score -1):

You could have some issues during summer as UTC does not change to Summer-Time.

I mean, during Winter the difference between UTC and Brussels is 1 hour, and during Summer the difference is 2 hours. Keep that in mind when you use Magento store timestamps, or UTC timestamps.